# basic android: syntax for switch statement instead of else-if

Tags: java, android, syntax, if-statement

I am working on an android beginner's tutorial that is a tip calculator. It runs properly, but I was wondering how to replace the else-if statement with a switch statement. Not that it is that important for the purposes of this program, but I'm just trying to wrap my mind around the syntax.

```
package com.android.tipcalc;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.view.View;

public class tipcalc extends Activity
{

    private EditText txtbillamount;
    private EditText txtpeople;
    private RadioGroup radiopercentage;
    private RadioButton radio15;
    private RadioButton radio18;
    private RadioButton radio20;

    private TextView txtperperson;
    private TextView txttipamount;
    private TextView txttotal;

    private Button btncalculate;
    private Button btnreset;

    private double billamount = 0;
    private double percentage = 0;
    private double numofpeople = 0; 
    private double tipamount = 0;
    private double totaltopay = 0;
    private double perperson = 0; 


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        initControls();

    }

    private void initControls()
    {
        txtbillamount = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtbillamount);
        txtpeople = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtpeople);
        radiopercentage = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.radiopercentage);
        radio15 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio15);
        radio18 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio18);
        radio20 = (RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.radio20);
        txttipamount=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txttipamount);
        txttotal=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txttotal);
        txtperperson=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtperperson);

        btncalculate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btncalculate);
        btnreset = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnreset);

        btncalculate.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick (View v){ calculate(); }});
        btnreset.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick (View v){ reset(); }});

    }

    private void calculate()
    {
    billamount=Double.parseDouble(txtbillamount.getText().toString());
    numofpeople=Double.parseDouble(txtpeople.getText().toString());

    if (radio15.isChecked()) {
        percentage = 15.00;
    } else if (radio18.isChecked()) {
        percentage = 18.00;
    } else if (radio20.isChecked()) {
        percentage = 20.00;
    }

    tipamount=(billamount*percentage)/100;
    totaltopay=billamount+tipamount;
    perperson=totaltopay/numofpeople;

    txttipamount.setText(Double.toString(tipamount));
    txttotal.setText(Double.toString(totaltopay));
    txtperperson.setText(Double.toString(perperson));        
    }

    private void reset()
    {
    txtbillamount.setText("");
    txtpeople.setText("");
    radiopercentage.clearCheck();
    radiopercentage.check(R.id.radio15);
    txttipamount.setText("...");
    txttotal.setText("...");
    txtperperson.setText("...");
    }
}
```

Comment: The language is Java, by the way. And IMO if-elseif-elseif looks good here.

Answer (score 6):

What the people above me said is correct, but for the sake of using a switch statement for the hell of it, you could set an `OnCheckedChangedListener` on your `RadioGroup`, then use a class like this:

```
private class MyCheckedChangedListener implements OnCheckedChangeListener {

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged( RadioGroup group, int checkedId ) {

    switch (checkedId) {
        case R.id.radio15:
            percentage = 15f;
            break;
        case R.id.radio18:
            percentage = 18f;
            break;
        case R.id.radio20:
            percentage = 20f;
            break;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Okay, I see how it works (and why.) Thank you all very much for your feedback!

Answer (score 1):

A `switch` is used on one variable - i.e. you have `x`, which can equal 3,5 or 7. Then you `switch x`  and give several cases - what to do on each possible value (you can also have a default case, when none of the given values match). In your case, you're checking several different variables, so `if ... else if ... else` is the correct method. You can, of course, make the radio boxes set a shared variable, which you can then `switch`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about the if-else statements in `calculate()`, you can't replace it directly with a switch statement. The case values in a switch statement need to be compile-time constants (either integers or enum values). Besides, the if-else here perfectly expresses the logic of what you are trying to do.

You *could* compute a "switch test value" based on the states of radio15, radio18, and radio20 (say, an integer from 0 to 8, based on the eight possible combinations of values) and switch on that, but I would strongly recommend against such an approach. Not only would it needlessly complicate and obscure the logic of what's going on, you would be cursing yourself if you needed to maintain the code six months from now after you had forgotten the clever trick.